# Save commerce price component

Tags: commerce, rules

I'm building simple VAT-module for commerce. 
The only thing it should do is to add a price component to the order total. 
I use a rules action to add the component and save it. The action it self works fine, but the component won't be saved or displayed. 
`hook_commerce_price_component_type_info()` is implemented and works. So what's wrong?

The code of the rule:

```
$order_total = $order->commerce_order_total['und'][0];
$tax_amount = round($order_total['amount'] / 1.19 * 0.19);
$tax_component = array (
                'amount' => $tax_amount,
                'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                'data' => array ()
                );
$order_total = commerce_price_component_add($order_total, 'tax', $tax_component, true ,  false);
$order->commerce_order_total['und'][0]['data'] = $order_total;
```

`debug()` returns this for the order total:

```
'commerce_order_total' => 
  array (
   'und' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'amount' => 32600,
        'currency_code' => 'EUR',
        'data' => 
        array (
          'components' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'name' => 'base_price',
              'price' => 
              array (
                'amount' => 30000,
                'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                'data' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              'included' => true,
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
              'name' => 'flat_rate_versand_6_5',
              'price' => 
              array (
                'amount' => 2600,
                'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                'data' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              'included' => true,
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'name' => 'tax',
              'price' => 
              array (
                'amount' => 5205,
                'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                'data' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              'included' => true,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [commerce_tax](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!tax!commerce_tax.module/DC) module, part of the Commerce suite.

It provides a VAT tax type with the associated price component information.

You can use it for code examples, or as the module itself to provide that functionality.

Comment: I didn't use the commerce_tax module because it gives me so wrong results, because of the calculation per line item.
The code doesn't really help me, just give another question: Do I need a custom line item to display a price component?